# Filtering out lines less than a specific length

Tags: image, image-processing, feature-detection, edge-detection

As shown in the attached image [For clarification only], there are three rows of lines with random length.
I would like to delete lines which are shorter than a constant N pixels.

Assumptions:

1. Lines are all in rows
2. Lines are 1 pixel width
3. Lines may be connected to borders.

I'm looking for any idea/guide which can help me with this. Thanks.[image]

Comment: what language are you using..?

Comment: The language doesn't matter, anything which is more comfortable for you is great. Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you simply count the amount of pixels in each connected component that describe a line and discard those with less than N pixels ? The posed question is either incorrect or this is a non-issue.

Comment: @mmgp: I'm looking for a short cut idea if there is any. Of course using many for-loops and if-statements always can do the job! Mainly, I should have an eye on not making the process too expensive. What do you think?

Comment: My earlier comment solves the task in `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of bits representing the binary image. The only way to do in less time is by further changing the representation of the initial image. But to do that, you take at least `O(n)`. It is up to you to efficiently implement this specific task as fast as you need.

Comment: @mmgp : so you think I gotta go with just bwlabel and then bwarea for each label and that all? How about a type of convolution or morphology thing that AutomaGically get rid of short lines?

Comment: That can be done too, but the former can be done a lot faster. You can do a custom implementation, so you skip `bwlabel` and `regionprops`. If no one beats me to it, later I will post one or two solutions using morphology.

Comment: One more thing! I think going with simply counting will be O(2n), cause once we scan through the image and count length of each line, next time short lines will be replaced by zeros. I'm I wrong?

Comment: O(2n) is O(n), the constant doesn't matter for asymptotic analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipping the possibility of directly handling the binary representation of the underlying image, and thus permitting a pretty fast implementation for this specific task, let us use Mathematical Morphology to (efficiently) solve it.

All you need here is a erosion with a horizontal line of length `n` followed by a morphological reconstruction. The former will completely remove lines shorter of length < `n`. The later will completely recover the eroded lines that were not removed.

Here is an example with `n = 25`. I used `ones(1, 25)` instead of `strel('line', 25, 0)` as the structuring element because the later doesn't guarantee that the actual line length is the one specified.

```
f = im2bw(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Uw0x.png'), 0);
g = imerode(f, strel('arbitrary', ones(1, 25)));
h = imreconstruct(g, f);
```

Eroded and reconstructed images:

[image] [image]

Comment: this should work. it might have been better to mention that the code is MATLAB, since the question was language-independent.

Comment: Can you be more specific by what you mean with "this should work" ? Also, I didn't bother specifying the language specifically because the problem is independent of language. This could easily be Octave code, or I could have made something that closely resembles the Matlab syntax, who knows.